# cocos2d - How can I play sound effect only when the user is touching?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, simpleaudioengine

How can I play a sound effect only when the user is touching? Just repeat it and stop when the user ends the touch.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your scene use

```
self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
```

And now you can respond to methods like ccTouchBegin or ccTouchEnd (forgot their names). So yeah, when touch begins, you can schedule a method which will play the sound effecr over and over. And when the touch ends, unschedule it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use SimpleAudioEngine, you can use playBackgroundMusic: (which defaults to loop) when you call ccTouchesBegan:withEvent:, then call stopBackgroundMusic: when you call ccTouchesEnd:withEvent:.

To use SimpleAudioEngine:

```
#import "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
```

To play the music in ccTouchesBegan:withEvent:

```
SimpleAudioEngine *sae = [SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine];
[sae preloadBackgroundMusic:@"MusicLoop.mp3"];
sae.backgroundMusicVolume = 0.5f;    // Sets the volume to 50%; this is optional
[sae playBackgroundMusic:@"MusicLoop.mp3"];
```

To stop the music in ccTouchesEnd:withEvent:

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] stopBackgroundMusic];
```